# Como escolher o que vai ser exibido do xml pelo php que está lendo?

Tags: php, xml

Tenho esse código rss do instagram em XML está nesse link: 
https://rss.app/feeds/wUySUmu0Kiy1c3uL.xml
Mas a parte que preciso é esta:

```html
<description>
<![CDATA[
<div> <img src="https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ef4a583cbe6ef13f207af32ee0780986/5E394ECF/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/71083885_707708566306382_5421780063674118290_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=102" style="width: 100%;"> <div>Olha a #quartadopão recheada de delícias com aquele precinho que só a gente tem. #correpracá!</div> </div>
]]>
</description>
```

O que eu quero pegar é apenas o texto, sem as tags, que ficaria:

> Olha a #quartadopão recheada de delícias com aquele precinho que só a
>   gente tem. #correpracá!

O que estou tentando é:

```html
<?php
$instaResult = simplexml_load_file('https://rss.app/feeds/wUySUmu0Kiy1c3uL.xml', NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA) or die("error");
$instagram_photos = $instaResult->channel->item[0]->enclosure['url'];

$instagram_date = $instaResult->channel->item[0]->pubDate;
echo str_replace('Wed','Quarta',$instagram_date);

$instagram_description = htmlentities((string)$instaResult[0]->channel->item[0]->description);

print $instagram_description;

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1800'; url='index.php'>"; //atualiza a cada 30 minutos
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=''>";
echo "<div class='fundo'>";
echo "</div>";

// DEFINE O FUSO HORARIO COMO O HORARIO DE BRASILIA
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
// CRIA UMA VARIAVEL E ARMAZENA A HORA ATUAL DO FUSO-HORÀRIO DEFINIDO (BRASÍLIA)
$hour = (int)date('G');
if ($hour >= 0 && $hour < 10)
{
 // 00:00 até 09:59
 $resp = "<img class='logo' src='logo.jpg' alt=''/>";
}
else
{
 // 10:00 até 23:59
 $resp = "<img class='img-responsive' src='{$instagram_photos}'/>";
}

echo $resp;
?>
```

Lembrando que eu já estou puxando a imagem e data da última postagem deste instagram, por isso o código a mais. A parte que ele puxa a descrição é:

```html
$instagram_description = htmlentities((string)$instaResult[0]->channel->item[0]->description);

print $instagram_description;
```

Se puderem me ajudar, desde já agradeço!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tenta isso :

```
$texto = '
        <description>
<![CDATA[
<div> <img src="https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ef4a583cbe6ef13f207af32ee0780986/5E394ECF/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/71083885_707708566306382_5421780063674118290_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=102" style="width: 100%;"> 
<div>Olha a #quartadopão recheada de delícias com aquele precinho que só a gente tem. #correpracá!</div> </div>
]]>
</description>';

 $result = trim(strip_tags(str_replace(array("<![CDATA[","]]>"),array("",""),$texto)));
 echo $result;
```

Comment: muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!